# Error while upserting Opportunity Team members

Tags: apex, externalid

I am trying to create `Opportunity Team Member` using External id's for `Opportunity` and `User`.

First of all I create an instance of Opportunity and User using their respective External Id's

```
 User teamUser = new User(User_External_ID__c =reader.getText());
 Opportunity req = new Opportunity(Opportunity_External_ID__c = reqNumber);
```

I then create an instance of Opportunity Team Member

```
   OpportunityTeamMember teamMember = new OpportunityTeamMember(Opportunity = req, User = teamUser, TeamMemberRole = 'FM');
```

Once I do an `upsert` of for `teamMember`, it gives me an error saying

```
 VF_PAGE_MESSAGE OpportunityTeamMember: bad field names on insert/update call: User, Opportunity

 System.DmlException: Upsert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_FIELD_FOR_INSERT_UPDATE, OpportunityTeamMember: bad field names on insert/update call: User, Opportunity: [User, Opportunity]

 VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT [1675]|e|"common.apex.runtime.impl.DmlExecutionException: Upsert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_FIELD_FOR_INSERT_UPDATE, OpportunityTeamMember: bad field names on insert/update call: User, Opportunity: [User, Opportunity]"|0x19dcd463
```

When I use `UserId` and `OpportunityId` instead of `User` and Opportunity

```
 OpportunityTeamMember teamMember = new OpportunityTeamMember(OpportunityId = req, UserId = teamUser, TeamMemberRole = 'FM');
```

It errors out saying expecting Salesforce id for Opportunity and User (which makes sense).

I am now not sure what I am missing when inserting Opportunity Team Members using external Id's for Opportunity and User.

Comment: What happens if you try setting the `OpportunityId` with `req.Id` and the `UserId` with `teamUser.Id`?

Comment: It wont allow me to insert Opportunity Team Members as at this point req.Id and teamUser.Id is both null since the instance created only has there External ID's.

Comment: And what if you use SOQL to get the Opportunity and User?

Comment: Maybe this will help http://bobbuzzard.blogspot.co.il/2012/03/create-parent-and-child-records-in-one.html

Comment: @ShimshonKorits I did read this blog however it is still giving me the same 'bad field name' error.

Comment: @Lex, I cannot use SOQL as there are many Opportunity Team Members I have to insert and will be running out of SOQL quires soon.

Comment: Can't you bulk load the Opportunity and Users in one query and put them in a Map or something to use them later on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see you're concerned with running into governor limits, it would be wise to "bulkify" your queries. I'm not sure where your `reader` or `reqNumber` variables are coming from in your code snippet, so I'll improvise.

First, (as @Lex mentioned) you'll want to create a set of your `User_External_ID__c` values and a set of your `Opportunity_External_ID__c` values. Query these two objects separately and then build a map from the External ID to the standard Salesforce ID so you can reference them later. Once that's done, you should be able to loop through and generate a new `OpportunityTeamMember` instance and add it to a list so you can make a single `insert` call. And you're done, with only 2 queries and 1 DML statement used.

Something like this should be a good place for you to start:

```
// sets of external IDs
Set<String> userExtIds = new Set<String>();
Set<String> oppExtIds = new Set<String>();
// populate sets of external IDs
for ( SomeObject reader : readers ) {
    userExtIds.add(reader.getText());
    oppExtIds.add(reader.getReqNumber());
}
// maps of external IDs -> SF IDs
Map<String, Id> userExtIdToSFIdMap = new Map<String, Id>();
Map<String, Id> oppExtIdToSFIdMap = new Map<String, Id>();
// populate user ID map
for ( User u : [select Id, User_External_ID__c from User where User_External_ID__c in :userExtIds] ) {
    userExtIdToSFIdMap.put(u.User_External_ID__c, u.Id);   
}
// populate opportunity ID map
for ( Opportunity o : [select Id, Opportunity_External_ID__c from Opportunity where Opportunity_External_ID__c in :oppExtIds] ) {
    oppExtIdToSFIdMap.put(o.Opportunity_External_ID__c, o.Id);
}
// build list of OpportunityTeamMember instances
List<OpportunityTeamMember> members = new List<OpportunityTeamMember>();
for ( SomeObject reader : readers ) {
    members.add(new OpportunityTeamMember(
                OpportunityId = oppExtIdToSFIdMap.get(reader.getReqNumber()),
                UserId = userExtIdToSFIdMap.get(reader.getText()),
                TeamMemberRole = 'FM')
            );
}
// insert OpportunityTeamMember records
insert members;
```

Like I mentioned before you'll want to determine the best way to populate those external IDs. For the purpose of the code I just assumed your `reader` variable was an instance of `SomeObject` and `reqNumber` could be returned by calling `reader.getReqNumber()`. This might not be the case, so you'll have to take it from there.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be:

```
OpportunityTeamMember teamMember = new OpportunityTeamMember(OpportunityId = req.Id, UserId = teamUser.Id, TeamMemberRole = 'FM');
```